# ADC reading in Low Power Mode (Stop Mode) in stm32L431RC Microcontroller

Tags: adc, stm32cubeide, consumption

I have encountered an issue while reading the ADC value. Additionally, I want to monitor the battery voltage via the ADC pin. The ADC works perfectly in run mode. However, once I implement it in low-power mode, it does not update the ADC value unless I manually reset the MCU. After resetting the MCU, the ADC updates its value. What could be causing this behavior, and how can I ensure the ADC updates properly in low-power mode?

To debug this issue, I've implemented a timer that starts the ADC in interrupt mode after a delay of 3 seconds. I couldn't configure the ADC in continuous mode because it remains in the wake-up mode, consuming power constantly. Consequently, the ADC consistently provides a value of 866 or 845, which is unexpectedly incorrect. In an attempt to resolve the issue, I replaced the normal timers with LPTIM, but the problem persists. I would appreciate it if someone could solve this issue or provide a clue that I can use to proceed further. Thanks.

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is to have it wake up for a second or so every 30 minutes to check the battery status then. ADCs probably require too much power to be viable in "low power mode" although I'm not sure for that particular CPU.